# How can i copy an image to my app's base path in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I'm using the Rhomobile API to capture photo using camera. The image is stored in blob folder of rhomobile and the path in rhom.

Below is the code i'm using,

```
def capture_image

  options = { :enable_editing => false }
  Camera::take_picture(url_for(:action => :callback_for_capture), options)

end 

def callback_for_capture

  photo_uri = @params['image_uri']
  photo = Photo.create({
    :id => generate_unique_id(),
    :photo_uri => photo_uri
  })

end
```

I need to copy the image file to my base folder of the application. Can anyone suggest me where and how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can go with the file api of rhomobile.

Comment: Thanks Ashis, but i'm bit new to rhomobile, can you show me some dummy code to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file api along with ruby binread method, and copy the image from the blob folder to base folder.

Check this,

```
def callback_for_capture

  photo_uri = @params['image_uri']
  photo = Photo.create({
    :id => generate_unique_id(),
    :photo_uri => photo_uri
  })

  # Store the image file to base app path
  file_name = photo_uri.to_s().split("/")[2]
  file_blob_path = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_blob_path(photo_uri))
  file_content = File.binread(file_blob_path)
  file_real_path = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_base_app_path(), file_name)
  f = File.new(file_real_path, "wb")
  f.write(file_content)
  f.close

end
```

More details over here http://ashiskumars.blogspot.in/2013/08/capturing-image-using-camera-api-uploading-to-server.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a try.